# How can I see a list of all open windows in a panel in Unity?

Tags: unity

Is there any reason why this is missing from Unity? It's a really helpful thing to have when you have a lot of windows open.

Answer (score 10):

I have developed an application indicator which shows a list of open windows. To keep with the Unity one-panel style, windows are accessed from an icon on the indicator panel.

## [Window-List](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejwigley/+archive/window-list)

**Category**: *Other, Window Management*

Window-list displays a list of current open desktop windows. Windows can be activated by selecting them from the menu list.

[image: window-list light theme]
[image: window-list dark theme]

Window-List is available for all versions of Ubuntu running Unity.

install via ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jwigley/window-list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install window-list
```

deb package is also available from the [launchpad repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejwigley/+archive/window-list).

run application by:

```
window-list
```

Once installed, open a window in the list by a right click.

Comment: great app, thank you! I'd be happy to see keyboard shortcuts for opening the menu and selecting the window :-)

Answer (score 7):

I've the same problem, but I found tint2. It is a bottom bar with all yours opened windows, it is available on main Ubuntu repo, and you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install tint2
```

To help configure tint2 you can use this python based gui:

```
wget http://tintwizard.googlecode.com/files/tintwizard-0.3.4.tar.gz
tar -zxvf tintwizard-0.3.4.tar.gz
./tintwizard.py
```

Source: http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/10/running-tint2-under-unity.html

Comment: +2 If I could.  This is exactly what I was looking for: just add a little menu bar with all the open windows to the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

A quite convenient alternative to a windows list is the windows preview inbuilt in the Unity Launcher. A minimized preview of all windows opened by a certain application is shown when clicking on its launcher icon. This is shown here on Unity 2D for three LibreOffice windows opened at the same time:

[image]

Just click on the window you want to work on to have it opened on top.

Note that all running applications that have a window opened are marked with tiny white dots on the left side of their panel icon.

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to see window previews from the current workspace and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to see those from all workspaces. You can close each window just by a middle click on it.

[image: Example screenshot showing visual list of open windows in Unity by shortcut pressing Super-W)]

(Hold down <kbd>Super</kbd> by itself for a list of shortcuts that can help sort windows.)

Answer (score 2):

Unity is a dock-based interface, the dock replaces the taskbar usually found on the gnome-panel. If i were you i would [log in with a classical mode](http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-11-04-natty-login-to-classic-gnome-2-desktop) rather than Unity, which will provide the gnome-panel and taskbar, and if you do want a dock, you can use Docky or [Cairo-Dock](http://www.glx-dock.org/). The latter will allow you more cutomisation.

Answer (score 2):

There is also,

[**Unity Window Quicklists**](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/03/16/unity-window-quicklists/)

> Unity Window Quicklists displays a list of open windows as quicklists
>   for each application on the Unity launcher, and you can use them to
>   switch between those windows. The quicklists are dynamic, meaning that
>   when a window is closed or a new window is open, the quicklists are
>   instantly updated.

[image]

More info http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/unity-window-quicklists-switch-between.html

Download it https://launchpad.net/~alanbell/+archive/unity

Answer (score 1):

The list of open windows in unity is shown as a dock (the launcher) would be, on the left side. If you need this on the bottom, you can use a dock like Docky or Avant Window Navigator, or possibly even a panel like the one in fluxbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run gnome-panel in Unity, see [How do I use the GNOME Panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39069/how-do-i-use-the-gnome-panel-in-unity)

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly enough, shantanu, I have taken a closer look at this and found graphical indication of multiple instances of an application in the Unity dock.  What I did not originally realize is that when I click on the appropriate icon in the dock, the multiple instances of the application are graphically depicted as window previews.  From there it is simply a matter of selecting the instance in which I am interested.

Comment: It's not an answer, please add your comments as a comment. By the way you can search within previews by typing.