# Equivalent of "GNOME Window Selector" for Unity (2D) panel?

Tags: 12.04, unity, unity-2d, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see a list of all open windows in a panel in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38505/how-can-i-see-a-list-of-all-open-windows-in-a-panel-in-unity)

On Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity 2D, is it possible to get a menu on the panel at the top of the screen that would allow me to quickly navigate to a particular window (no matter which workspace it happens to be on)?

On Gnome 2 this used to be available with the [GNOME Window Selector applet](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.32/panel-windowselector.html.en).

thanks!
~l

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate for now - the indicator in the linked answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Added an answer to the linked question on one of my favourite Unity features - the windows preview ;)