# Set the launched application's icons to be top, not side bar

Tags: gnome, launcher, icons, gui

I just recently started using ubuntu for things, other than the terminal. The Side menu is pretty nice, however I am using 3-4 programs (in the definition that they have an icon and appear on the side bar), so most of the space the task bar requires is not used.

Is there a way to have the icons on the top, where the clock, sound and email are? Some programs, like skype or spotify appear there. I want all programs to appear there and, if possible, to have icons by default and start the programs from there.

Is it possible ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/144981/159545) works for you, if not, have in mind that Unity have been designed with certain guidelines. In particular, the [indicators](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators) are not used for window/task management. You can set the Launcher to auto-hide and install a dock/panel and configure it to suit your needs. There are *many* dock/panel alternatives: `docky`, `cairo-dock`, `xfce4-panel`, `gnome-panel`, `tint2`, `lxpanel`, ....

You could also install KDE or Xfce, which can be easily configured to have a panel on the top as you wish. The packages are named `kde-runtime` and `xfce4`.